# Is there a way to keep text elements from combining in Adobe PDF creater/editer?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I'm trying to create a fillable PDF form using Adobe Acrobat DC. I'm creating separate text elements to use as field labels (name, phone number, etc.) but they keep automatically combining with other nearby text elements, making it impossible to move each one around on the page independently. This is severely limiting my ability to fine-tune the formatting, especially when trying to move the labels next to their individual interactive fields.

I tried a simple right-click to see if there was an "ungroup" function or something, but I didn't see any options. I also poked around to see if there's some kind of default setting for grouping nearby text elements that may be switched on, and couldn't find anything like that either.

A screenshot of this is attached. "Name", "Street Address", and "City" were all created as separate text fields, but then somehow snapped together into a single text element.

[image: example of automatically combined text fields shown in Adobe editor]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When the PDF got created, this was considered to be connected. When I have this situation, I usually copy the block, as many times needed, and delete the according unwanted text. This will create individual Objects in the PDF.

Comment: Thank you for the info, @MaxWyss. Unfortunately, I have tried copying and deleting, but they inevitably recombine if they get too close to one another!! As of now I'm just trying to keep them far apart, but that can be so inconvenient when you want to do single-page or single-sheet forms.